# error on compiling : The "ResolveLibraryProjectImport" task failed inexpectedly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created the application in crossplotform,on running my application it is showing the following error.I have tried of cleaning solution and rebuilding it again but no luck,i even tried reducing the path of this application and also unistalled and reinstalled xamarin.forms from nuget packages,even after doing all this again same error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Tool
Error       The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'SnovasysChat.exe, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'SnovasysChat.exe.dll'
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String fullName)
   at Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String fileName)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() SMChat.Android
```

How to resolve this.

Comment: I have seen this issues when msbuild od adb hang up. Try to reboot your system

Comment: Thanks for response @Balakrishna,I tried this earlier but no change,the error is appearing again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair the Visual Studio. I would suggest, you use Visual Studio 2017 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to open VS as administrator, or try to update to the latest VS studio version. I used to have this problem, and after the update it was solved.